Order SQL results by timestamp and another field simultaneously
I have an SQL table (in Microsoft SQL Server 2019) tracking inventory orders. Let's call it Orders. It looks like this:



ID
Workcell
EnteredOn




1
T1A
2024-04-25 13:50:01.990


2
T1B
2024-04-25 14:22:18.727


3
DTA
2024-04-25 14:22:55.237


4
552-8A
2024-04-25 14:34:56.890


5
T1A
2024-04-25 14:51:01.173


6
DTA
2024-04-25 15:22:08.527



I need to sort it like the below. In words, I need to cluster like workcells together, and sort these clusters by the oldest timestamp within each unique cluster.
Since T1A (ID 1) is the oldest timestamp in the sample data, the every other T1A entry (in this case only ID 5) should come immediately after it in ascending timestamp order, and then comes T1B since this workcell has the next oldest timestamp after filtering out all the T1A entries, and so on.



ID
Workcell
EnteredOn




1
T1A
2024-04-25 13:50:01.990


5
T1A
2024-04-25 14:51:01.173


2
T1B
2024-04-25 14:22:18.727


3
DTA
2024-04-25 14:22:55.237


6
DTA
2024-04-25 15:22:08.527


4
552-8A
2024-04-25 14:34:56.890



If I ORDER BY timestamp, I can't order by workcell. If I order by workcell and then timestamp, it will put the workcells in alphabetical order, which is of course not what I want. I think I need to get creative inside of my ORDER BY statement, but I don't know how exactly to do this.

Look at Row_number and partition by function.

order by MIN(EnteredOn) over(partition by Workcell), Workcell, EnteredOn perhaps

You can use MIN window function to calculate the minimum date per grouping (in this case you want it to be per Workcell) and use it for your sort:
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, N'T1A', N'2024-04-25 13:50:01.990')
    ,   (2, N'T1B', N'2024-04-25 14:22:18.727')
    ,   (3, N'DTA', N'2024-04-25 14:22:55.237')
    ,   (4, N'552-8A', N'2024-04-25 14:34:56.890')
    ,   (5, N'T1A', N'2024-04-25 14:51:01.173')
    ,   (6, N'DTA', N'2024-04-25 15:22:08.527')
) t (ID,Workcell,EnteredOn)
ORDER BY MIN(EnteredOn) OVER(PARTITION BY Workcell), Workcell, EnteredOn

I added Workcell as second order by for tie-breaking, in case there are multiple groups with same minimum value.
Output:



ID
Workcell
EnteredOn




1
T1A
2024-04-25 13:50:01.990


5
T1A
2024-04-25 14:51:01.173


2
T1B
2024-04-25 14:22:18.727


3
DTA
2024-04-25 14:22:55.237


6
DTA
2024-04-25 15:22:08.527


4
552-8A
2024-04-25 14:34:56.890



